# How to convert a datetime from one timezone to another using dayjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, dayjs

I'm trying to convert a datetime from the timezone UTC+1 to the timezone where the user is located in.
I get the datetime from the DB which is located in UTC+1 but the datetime should be shown to the user in his timezone.

For example:

**08 Nov 2020 15:00** (UTC+1) should be shown to a user in San Francisco as **08 Nov 2020 06:00** (UTC-8)

I tried it using dayjs like this:

```
let dayjs = require('dayjs');
let utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc'); // dependent on utc plugin
let timezone = require('dayjs/plugin/timezone');
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)
let datetime = dayjs('2020-11-08 15:00').tz(dayjs.tz.guess()).format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(datetime);
```

I started testing it by changing the timezone in the chrome devtools but I always keep getting **Sun, 08 Nov 2020 15:00** no matter which timezone I'm currently in.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using **dayjs v1.9.5**

Comment: I don't know dayjs, but I'd guess '2020-11-08 15:00' is parsed as local, and *tz.guess* will also be local so there is no shift. If you want the string parsed as UTC +1, then something like '2020-11-08T15:00:00+01:00' should work.

Comment: did you find a solution? i came into a similar problem

Comment: I know that it's not a good solution but at some time I gave up and used momentJS.
Much better documentation in my opinion.